# global transformable settings for solution

Tags: .net, msbuild, configuration-files

Solution with multiple project types.
All of them have a reference to a common dll.

Would like to:

1. publicly access configuration settings from any project (connection strings, etc..) example: commondll.My.MySettings.Default.Setting1
2. transform each setting depending on the build configuration (DEV,QA,PROD)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Normally use configuration files (app.config, web.config)

Comment: I would have to copy the settings to each project configuration file. Need them in one central place.

Comment: Configuration file in start-up project would be the only one you need to change

Comment: the solution has multiple startup projects